# Which MySQL data types should I not be quoting during an INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql

As a beginner with MySQL, I want to get this right. My main hangup right now is the DECIMAL type.

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

> As of MySQL 5.0.3, values for DECIMAL
>   columns are represented using a binary
>   format that packs nine decimal (base
>   10) digits into four bytes. Before
>   MySQL 5.0.3, DECIMAL columns are
>   represented as strings and storage
>   requirements are...

So the question is, which data types should I NOT be quoting during an INSERT? I assume I should not use quotes around any of the INTs, FLOAT, DOUBLE and REAL. What about DECIMAL? Any I'm forgetting?

**EDIT:**

I understand MySQL will "convert to the proper type," but I want to get the right answer regardless. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from the quotation that decimal values are stored in the hard disk as four byte binary values from 5.0.3 onwards, but I expect them to be represented using quotes for locale safeness. Multiple locales use different decimal "point" symbols, thousand separators and another symbols, these can't be handle by the MySQL query parser, but by the data type parser that will parse the strings as decimals. I expect this to also apply to all floating point types: float, double and real too.

Comment: Additionally, digits in precision math are (almost) always represented by their language characters to keep precision and not get confused with ~`FLOAT(1.11111)`.

Comment: That's also what I've concluded from some further reading from a slightly older MySQL book I've got. Thanks for the help!